# Sql script that requires connection to a remote server

Tags: mysql, select, command-line

I have been given a sql script to execute that populates a table from the result of a query on a table that is on a remote server.. How do I select the remote server and relevant database as below?

```
 INSERT INTO Table (Field1, Field2, Field3) 
 SELECT 'REMOTE_SERVER', Field1, Field2, Field3 
 FROM Table where ........;
```

Thanks
Further to my question 
If was going to do this using PHP how would I do it? I am already connecting to both servers as follows:

```
 $dbh1 = mysql_connect($host1, $user1, $password1); $dbh2 = mysql_connect($host2, $user2,$password2, true);
```

with $dbh2 being the remote server

Comment: How are you accessing your Mysql server?  Through a PHP script? The command line? phpMyAdmin?  Whichever it is, your question is about how to use that tool to connect to a remote server.  So add a tag to the question for that.

Comment: Hi Ben ...  good point from MySQL cammand line ideally

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, your only options would be to use the [federated storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/federated-storage-engine.html) or to pipe the data through a custom script.

Note that the Federated Engine does not optimize sub-queries as strictly as it might - and therefore can be rather slow when dealing with very datasets

Comment: Hi ...  if was going to do this using PHP how would I do it?  I am already connecting to both servers as follows:                   $dbh1 = mysql_connect($host1, $user1, $password1); 
$dbh2 = mysql_connect($host2, $user2, $password2, true);                                                              with $dbh2 being the remote server

Comment: @Peter : Please edit your question to include this info. Good Luck!